# Web App: Bypass middleman when retrieving data from database

Tags: java, javascript, jdbc, playframework-2.0, server-side

Setup:

- Postgresql-postgis database on the server
- [Play Framework](http://www.playframework.com/) 2.0 used for server-side logic (Java)
- Millions of data rows in the database
- Client taking data in via XHR arraybuffer request

In a typical web application, when the client wants data, it would send a request to the server, the logic would submit the query, the data would be returned to the server, and the server would forward on the data to the client.

As Java would need to be a middleman between the client and the database, it adds extra processing onto the data before I can pass it on. What I'm asking is, is there a way I can query the database using normal server to database queries, but send the data directly from the database to the client? I ask because there are cases where I need to pass millions of rows of data, so any optimisation would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that your client speaks PostgreSQL's protocol via libpq (or whatever)? Or are you looking for a lightweight way to pass JSON/XML results back to the client-app?

Comment: @RichardHuxton I'm seeking a way/language/framework which will allow me to get data from the database to the browser (client) with as little middleman processing as possible.

Comment: so your client talks PostgreSQL protocol directly? If not, you'll need to provide a hint as to what it can/does talk.

Comment: I think there's a bit of confusion going on. Think simpler. All I have thus far is a database. I need to get millions of rows from a server to a clients browser. What server-side language/method/framework could I use to minimise the work done by the server to get the data to the client? I.e Using Java to retrieve data would mean that Java needs to perform object mapping before then forwarding the data. Are there ways to reduce the middlemans work? Idea: open two sockets somehow and append db stream to the server-client stream socket.

Comment: Have the client query the database directly (with appropriate SSL+auth) or write a thin wrapper in [language of choice]. In either case you probably want to stream a cursor rather than fetching the entire result-set in one go.